# Backpressure mechanism in Synchronous method by Project Reactor

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

The story is: When a logical scenario has happened, at some point in the flow I need to call a web service from another application. This service is blocking so my thread block until the remote server answers me. When I knew reactor concept I decided to migrate the service call part to reactor world and do backpressure mechanism on that because sometimes the remote server is going to be slow.

In other words, I have the following design:

[image]

In this model, **MyApp** has a thread pool that each thread begins when a new request income into **MyApp** and then call **Remote Server** and block until **Remote Server** answers. 
In the model in my mind, as the following request threads don't block for **Remote Server** and the **Reactive Part** calls **Remote Server**. It means I want to release **MyApp** thread and process another request.

[image]

I wrote some code like the following:

```
Flux<Integer> flux = Flux.generate(sick-> //call Remote Server service );
flux.onBackpressureBuffer(100, BufferOverflowStrategy.ERROR)
    .subscribe(s->System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - result is ==>> " + s)
```

The important option for me is backpressure (in the above code I simple it to be 100 but I want a dynamic behavior). I want to reduce request when **Remote Server** is going to be slow. I don't know is the flux right or not because I thought I have to have a **Flux** that accept each request from **My App** and then call Remote Server in an infinitive loop.

Comment: have you tried onBackpressureBuffer()/onBackpressureDrop()/ onBackpressureError()/onBackpressureLatest() without params i.e. limiting to maxsize

Comment: No, I didn't try them. Actually, I'm in a prior step. In other words, I'm not sure that my way is correct.

Comment: I would say, you are on right path, all you need is unbounded demand instead of request(n) which you can get with onBackpressureBuffer()/onBackpressureDrop()/ onBackpressureError()/onBackpressureLatest(). However for your application to be reactive, make sure everything is reactive i.e. reactive repo, reactive DB, reactive server, and of course reactive framework ( webflux etc )

Comment: If I redesign MY App, your speech is correct and I can do everything reactive but my now My App is traditional and I want to do reactive only IO-bounded points.

Comment: atleast without the reactive server I don't think you would be able to do since request thread will be blocked everytime for worker threads/ data. reactive server with have event loop which will execute callback when the data is available or pushed i.e. subscription  releasing the thread for other work